# Azure DevOps Work Item Details Import (Including formatting)

Tags: excel, import, azure-devops, user-stories

I've got a number of user stories that I want to upload to my project site in DevOps that are currently sat within an Excel spreadsheet.  Not the end of the world since I can use the Office Integration add-in to import the relevant data values.

I can't seem to do this for the description and acceptance criteria fields though since they're multi-line text boxes, or at least not as I'd like.  When I import the data it removes the line breaks and other formatting, and so everything becomes that bit more difficult to read. Is there any way that I can import from my Excel spreadsheet and keep the formatting??

Comment: try to add HTML elements in the excel, for example: `</br>` for link break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this doc: [Import or update rich-text fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops#import-or-update-rich-text-fields)

> The description and acceptance criteria field are rich-text fields. Rich-text fields are HTML formatted fields.

So when you export the work item, the description and acceptance criteria field contain the HTML tag.

As far as I know, the html format is  used to keep formatting elements in the exported/import content.

If you want to make changes in excel, you need to add html tag in description and acceptance criteria field.